# CPLEX Optimization Studio

Tags: optimization, cplex, ampl

I am starting to work with CPLEX Optimization Studio, and I am wondering if there are any quick start guides, hello world examples, etc. Some things I would like to be able to do include loading and running a simple LP or ILP through the Optimization Studio, interacting with AMPL model and data files, and integrating CPLEX into C++ or Java code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First place to look would be the examples that are included with CPLEX studio when you install it. On my windows 7 PC the CPLEX examples are in:

C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1251\cplex\examples

while the OPL examples are in:

C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1251\opl\examples\opl

There are lots of examples there, particularly the CPLEX examples, including what you are looking for in C++, Java, C# etc...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @TimChippingtonDerrick CPLEX Studio includes documentation and examples. However, AFAIK it doesn't provide any special facilities for working with AMPL models and data. For these you might want to try [AMPL IDE](http://www.ampl.com/IDE/beta.html) instead.